# Angular element with Hot Module Replacement causing duplicated customElements.define

Tags: angular, web-component, angular-elements, hot-module-replacement

In my `DoBootstrap`, I setup the Angular element with

```js
    const webComponentTag = 'ui-button'
    customElements.define(webComponentTag,  createCustomElement(UIButtonComponent, {injector}));
```

Note there is no way to remove a definition from registered custom elements.

If I serve with `--hmr`, I will get this error during reload:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition to check if the element already has already been defined.

```js
if (!customElements.get('ui-button')) {
  const webComponentTag = 'ui-button'
  customElements.define(webComponentTag,  
  createCustomElement(UIButtonComponent, {injector}));
}
```